# LINQ get the average of columns and write to csv

Tags: c#, linq, csvhelper

I'm trying to select cartoon characters by their classification, then average their attack and defense properties. Then finally write it to a csv file.
input:

```
classfication | attack | defense
   Wolf           5        6
   Wolf           2       12
```

output:

```
attack_average | defense_average
     3.5               9
```

I wrote a code that can get the averages but can't use 'ToList()' on them and can't write them into one csv file because I have two variables.

```
            var list = list.Where(x => x.classfication.Equals("Wolf"));
            var def = list.Select(x => x.defense).Average();
            var atk = list.Select(x => x.attack).Average();

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\Example\\Example.csv"))
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
               csv.WriteRecords(def);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you could just create a new list or array based on the data you already have.

```
csv.WriteRecords(new[]{new { attack_average = atk, defense_average = def }});
```

But it may be more useful to think in terms of "grouping" the original input, and getting averages per group.

```
        var averagesByClass = list
            .Where(x => x.classfication.Equals("Wolf")) // might not want this?
            .GroupBy(x => x.classfication)
            .Select(g => new 
                {
                    classification = g.Key, // Remove this if you don't want it
                    attack_average = g.Select(x => x.defense).Average(),
                    defense_average = g.Select(x => x.attack).Average(),
                })
            .ToList();

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\Example\\Example.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
           csv.WriteRecords(averagesByClass);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer, works perfectly. :)